# cant figure out how to include a file based on another echo

Tags: php

i am trying to include another file based on the page its on.

```
<?php echo $this->artist->gname; ?>
```

as i am sure you could guess that first  echo will display the  database field i want.
now i need to include a page. thats named the field gname.

So gname in database  could be sam

i would need to include    http://www.website.com/folder/sam.php

Now on another page  the gname is  Frank

http://www.website.com/folder/frank.php would be called.

i am not a coder so i  cant figure out this. i tried to include a couple different ways  but could not figure it out.

and i tried to search but dont know  what to search for.  everything  talking about includes is  totally different then what i am doing.

Comment: `<?php include 'http://www.website.com/folder/'.$this->artist->gname.'.php'; ?>`

Answer (score 0):

Instead of *echoing* the variable, use it to build the path to the included script:

```
include($this->artist->gname . ".php");
```

Make sure the variable is not filled in by user input, because it could be a serious vulnerability. Otherwise, you will need to check and/or sanitize value before using it.

Comment: thanks  the database field is  through the backend of joomla i just couldnt figure out how to display it thanks appreciate it